# Images hidden from wordpress gallery

Tags: gallery

We recently move some articles to a new domain. Now the problem is the images though on the site don't show up in gallery and when you search for them you don't see it.

But upload image file with similar name and wordpress adds a number to it.

For example this image is not showing up in gallery and searching for it is not found https://thetarpan.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/climbing-gourami.jpg but uploading image with the same name results to this https://thetarpan.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/climbing-gourami-2.jpg

2 has been added.

Edit: Seems they are using same date, even though the second image was uploaded on 03/05/2020

Answer (score 0):

If you don't move to gallery from db, gallery not showing items. Because gallery is not showing up all files in uploads folder, show only uploaded from wordpress, mean: if you want to see any images on gallery you must be upload from wordpress (admin panel, codeline or etc)

Comment: i upload from wordpress media manager